# Create Ubuntu Proxy Server with network interface binding

Tags: networking, ubuntu, proxy, openvpn, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to create an Ubuntu server which acts as a proxy. The server has OpenVPN running. The server should route all traffic which comes through the proxy, through this VPN.

I've tried using Squid to accomplish this, but I can't seem to find the option in the configs and web.

Is there a way to bind Squid (or another proxy application) to a specific network interface? (named 'tun0' in 'ifconfig' in my case)

Answer (score 2):

`http_port` seems to be the option you are looking for. [Documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/http_port/) states that `http_port` accepts `port`, `hostname:port` and `1.2.3.4:port` as format. You could specify the IP address of the `tun0` interface to bind Squid to that particular interface.

For example:

```
http_port 192.168.42.1:8080
```

Comment: It seems like this didn't really work for me. I did found another solution: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/tcp_outgoing_address/ But as the vpn doesn't always return a fixed IP, it's getting a bit hard. It'd be easier to just say: bind to 'tun0'

Comment: Maybe bind Squid to `127.0.0.1` and write some `iptables` rules which route incoming packets to this address. For example:
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -i tun0 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8080`